# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in SOAP Call

Tags: php, soap

I'm creating a SOAP import and I receive the result as an id, and resultcode

My code

```
    $param = new stdClass();

    $param->item = new stdClass();

    $param->item->mainItem      = new stdClass();
    $param->item->mainItem->id  ="12345";

    $param->item->itemCode      ="item_1603";
    $param->item->title         ="TEST 01";
    $param->item->description   ="Description goes here";

    $clientSOAP = new SoapClient($urlWSDL, $options);
    $clientSOAP->__setLocation($loc);   
    $result = $clientSOAP->ImportItem($param);
```

..

Execution show this error

Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

in line

$result = $clientSOAP->ImportItem($param);

I've tested in SOAPUI, and worrks well, giving this result:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:ImportItemResponseMsg 
            xsi:type="ns1:ImportItemResponse" 
            xmlns:ns1="http://item.webservice.host.xxx.com" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <s151:returnCode xmlns:s151="http://webservice.host.xxx.com">0</s151:returnCode>
                <s152:returnMessage xmlns:s152="http://webservice.host.xxx.com"/>
                <itemId>5046</itemId>
        </ns1:ImportItemResponseMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I ssume the response is an object, but I cannot handle it. Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: What are you sending with SOAPUI? I am guessing mainItem is a string in SOAPUI and an object in PHP...

Comment: I'm sending this<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:con="http://item.webservice.host.xxx.com"  xmlns:xm="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <con:importItemRequestMsg>
         <item>
            <mainItem>
               <id>12345</id>
            </mainItem>
            <itemCode>item_1603</itemCode>
            <title>TEST 01</title>
            <description>Description goes here</description>
         </item>
      </con:importItemtRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: I dont think that is the correct thing you are sending, since it is invalid XML... `con:importItemRequestMsg` and `con:importItemtRequestMsg` dont match, there are semicolons after the values in the envelope... This should not render a result!

Comment: I think the error should be produced in the variable handling, not in the variable gneration (in this case variable "$result")

Comment: In soapUi there is a XML validator, I've tested and the xml is ok. Moreover, the result is correct too